# Can Capybara be used in Calabash-android for browser automation?

Tags: capybara, calabash-android

I want to open a browser from Android application for automation through calabash-android using ruby. Is it possible by using Capybara (`gem install capybara`) or some other method?

Answer (score 1):

Divya!

`Capybara` - Web browser automation framework.

`Calabash-android` - Mobile app automation framework.

Both this framework is based on Cucumber(a command line tool)

---

You can use `Capybara` to run the test in `system web browser` as well as `mobile web browser`. So my answer is YES.

Comment: capybara is not possible with ruby version 1.9 or need to update ? Did you  ever use capybara with calabash-android ?

Comment: 1. Capybara requires Ruby 1.9.3 or later  2.  No.